# Application trying to use .NET 4.0 instead of 4.6 - both are installed on the machine

Tags: .net-framework

Application trying to use .NET 4.0 instead of 4.6 - both are installed on the machine. The app NEEDS to run on 4.6 but in the windows error logs I can see that when I try to open the app (which crashes with a generic "Something has caused this app to stop working blah blah") it's using 4.0.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6 is a direct replacement for .NET Framework 4.0.  .NET Framework 4.0 cannot be installed on a system that has .NET Framework 4.6 installed.  Unless you are running Windows 7, .NET Framework 4.6, cannot be uninstalled.  If the system has .NET Framework 4.6 installed, then the an .NET Framework 4.6 application, should run without any modifications to the system.  **It is not possible for both to be installed on the system (through the installer or Windows Update).**    Please explain why you believe that to be the case.

Comment: The Windows app error logs say 4.0 in them but I can see that 4.6 is installed

Comment: Which makes sense since .NET 4.6 is a direct replacement for .NET Framework 4.0